# Multiple Lightboxes on a single page using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, overlay, lightbox, photo, preview

I have multiple preview photos on a single page, and I wish for each preview photo to have its own lightbox which enlarges the photo.
But when I open the second photo on the page, the lightbox image is the larger version of the first image on the page.
I am using HTML and CSS with minimal java

This is my code for HTML

```
<div id="graphic">
<h2><span>Graphic Art</span></h2>
<!--Below is the code for the clickable Sloth Photo with an opening Light Box-->
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
<img src="images/graphicart/sloth-small.jpg" width="200px"></a></p>
<div id="light" class="white_content"><img src="images/graphicart/sloth-large.jpg" width="600px">
<br>
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
</div>

<div id="Separator">
</div>

<div id="Photo1">
<h2><span>Photography<span></h2>
<!--Below is the code for the clickable photos with an opening Light Box-->
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
<img src="images/photography/art-small.jpg" width="200px"></a></p>
<div id="light" class="white_content"><img src="images/photography/art-large.jpg" width="600px">
<br>
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

And the coresponding CSS is:

```
.black_overlay {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 200%;
background-color: black;
z-index:1001;
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
opacity:.80;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.white_content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 15%;
left: 20%;
width: 54%;
height: 75%;
padding: 16px;
border: 16px solid orange;
background-color: white;
z-index:1002;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS is fine, make sure that all of your ID's are pointing to the right image.  Right now all of your id's are pointing to light. If you have changed the second image ID's to light2, then you lightboxes should work.